# Parsing a table data in dictionary format using docx

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-docx

I am trying to parse a particular set of table data using Python docx module.

The table data looks something like this 
[image]

I need to retrieve the "Authorities" and respective "Versions" in key value format, so that I can use that data for further processing.

I am unable to iterate over the dictionary if I use -

```
d = OrderedDict(zip(table.cell(rowNo, 0).text, table.cell(rowNo, 2).text))
```

which gives me orderedDictionary but I cant access the values using `d['Juno']`
which I am expecting to give me `4.5.6`

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('myfile.docx')

    for table in document.tables:
        printTable = False
        rowNo = 0;
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                if cell.text == "Table2":
                    printTable = False
            if printTable:
                print (table.cell(rowNo, 0).text + '=' + table.cell(rowNo, 2).text)
            for cell in row.cells:
                if cell.text == "Authorities":
                    printTable = True
            rowNo += 1
```

I am getting the data in below format after parsing -

```
Juno=4.5.6
Acrux=3.5.6
Mars=5.6.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a dictionary and achieve this -

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('myfile.docx')
data = {}
for table in document.tables:
    printTable = False
    rowNo = 0;
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            if cell.text == "Table2":
                printTable = False
        if printTable:
            data[table.cell(rowNo, 0).text] = table.cell(rowNo, 2).text
        for cell in row.cells:
            if cell.text == "Authorities":
                printTable = True
        rowNo += 1
print (data)
```

Will give you the expected data in dictionary format